# How can I join the object?

Tags: objects

I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd> but it doesn't work, how can I join this object? The objects are in different layers.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, some more information on what you tried would be helpful. In the screenshot for example it looks like the objects are not even selected. All objects that should be joined have to be selected, and one has to be the active object (brighter outline than the others) which will be the one the others are joined into.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann when I do join the object are selected together, in the screen not

Comment: @Lila That's what Chris means about lack of clarification... I do not know that you have selected them, it's not visible, you didn't describe it, you just said "I have tried Ctrl+J but it didn't work" - but since it usually should work I guess there must be something more to say about your trial which keeps it from working.

Comment: Oh I see, now that I have downloaded the file. In the screenshot there are three objects you said "join this object" - no idea which one you mean, but since two looked(!) like mesh objects, I suppose you mean those two. But the head is a mesh, and the bullet or whatever it is, is a curve - you cannot join meshes and curves together. They are two completely different kinds of objects. You could only convert the curve into a mesh and then join them, but in this case you cannot edit the curve the way you did before.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann the circle is the shape of the second object

Comment: As @GordonBrinkmann explained, you can't join objects together if they are of different types. So if you want to join a curve object into a mesh object: that isn't possible. You first need to convert that curve object into a mesh object via RMB > Convert To > Mesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object are different type, the head is a mesh and the other is a curve. I need to convert the other in a mesh. (like is say in the comment prevously)